# PySpark: Take average of a column after using filter function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using the following code to get the average age of people whose salary is greater than some threshold.

```
dataframe.filter(df['salary'] > 100000).agg({"avg": "age"})
```

the column age is numeric (float) but still I am getting this error.

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o86.agg. 
: scala.MatchError: age (of class java.lang.String)
```

Do you know any other way to obtain the avg etc. without using `groupBy` function and SQL queries.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Aggregation function should be a value and a column name a key:

```
dataframe.filter(df['salary'] > 100000).agg({"age": "avg"})
```

Alternatively you can use `pyspark.sql.functions`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, avg

dataframe.filter(df['salary'] > 100000).agg(avg(col("age")))
```

It is also possible to use `CASE .. WHEN`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

dataframe.select(avg(when(df['salary'] > 100000, df['age'])))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this too:

```
dataframe.filter(df['salary'] > 100000).groupBy().avg('age')
```